# Measurability of a set in Littlewood 3rd principle

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

All sets are real and $m$ is the Lebesgue outer measure

***Theorem:***

$E$ measurable with $mE$ finite. $f_n:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ measurable functions and $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise in $E$. Then, given $\epsilon$, $\delta >0$ there is a set $A \subseteq E$ measurable with $mA\le \delta$ and such that for all $x \in E-A$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$, for $n \ge N$, where $N$ is some natural number.

***Proof:***

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Define for each $i$ in $\mathbb{N}$, 
$$G_i=\{x \in E \,s.t.\, |f_i(x)-f(x)| \ge \epsilon\} $$
Define then : $E_k=\bigcup\limits_{j=k}^{\infty} G_{j}$

We see that $\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} E_{m}=\emptyset $, else there wouldn't be puntual convergence. Also, Each $G_k$ is contained in $E$,and thus so is each 
$E_j$. Then $m(E_j)<\infty$ for each $j$. Also, for each $n$, $E_{n+1}\subseteq E_n$. Then we can apply a proposition which says $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} m(E_k)=m(\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} E_{m})=m(\emptyset)=0.$
Finally, choose $N$ big enough so that $m(E_N)<\delta$. This $E_N$ serves as the $A$ of the theorem.

***Questions:***

1)Why is $A$ measurable? I see $A$ is some $E_k$, and that $E_k$ is a countable union if $G_j's$. But i can't see why the $G_j$ would be measurable either [Also, to apply the proposition of the limit we need each $E_k$ measurable].

2) This theorem doesn't assure uniform convergence in $E-A$, right? Because the set $A$ happens to depend on $\epsilon$, as far as I see.

Comment: The G's are measurable as preimages of measurable functions. Also this line of reasoning does actually give uniform convergence if you do it right...

Comment: @Ian: May you be more specific about which functions are the G_i's preimage of?

Comment: $|f_i-f| {}{}{}$.

Comment: @Ian Yeah, I'd tought about that, but $|f_i-f|=$ |     |  o $f_i-f$ And that order is not convenient...I know that if the continuous function is to the right, then the composition is measurable.. But here the continuous is to the left. Does it hold anyway?

Comment: Sure, consider how simple the level sets of absolute value are...

Comment: Seems I was mistaken, when the continuous is to left of the composition it is easy. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ian I would say as preimages of open sets under measurable functions.

Comment: Sure, that was sloppy...